# Ubuntu no wired network

Tags: networking, wired

After upgrading to 16.10 I have no wired connection. Wifi is ok. Windows wired network is also ok.

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:367d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth  -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I suggest running `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`. Reboot and test.

Comment: @Pilot6 Just tired. Doesn't help. Still the same.

Comment: Then it is hard to tell. What do you mean by "no wired connection"? Disable your wireless connection and test.

Comment: Use 'ifconfig -a' and look if you see your ethernet there and if yes, add the info about your ethernet to your post. I recommend you to read this -> https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: @Pilot6 Hi, how can I get back to r8169? Thanks!

Comment: You can get back by `sudo apt purge r8168-dkms`

Comment: @Pilot6 It doesn't work. I can't get back to 8169. It's still 8168!

Comment: Did you reboot after that?

Comment: @Pilot6 I am replying you in windows10 now. Because after I reboot, I lost my wifi connection in ubuntu as well. Can someone help?

Comment: Something is wrong with your system. I suggest to re-install. And it is not recommended to install 16.10 for a newbie. it is hard to guess what is wrong. Probably the upgrade was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been to the realtek website and downloaded the most recent drivers for your controller?

I am a novice user and spent many hours searching for an answer to why I cannot connect to my internet using an ethernet cable. After entering lines and lines of code with absolutely nothing working, I simply went to the Realtek website, downloaded the linux drivers for my network controller (r8125), ran the "autorun.sh" script, reboot and I was able to gain a network connection. I did this using a USB tether to my phone's cellular connection.

If anyone who has a realtek network controller cannot connect to ethernet, try downloading the latest linux drivers before entering a thousand lines of code that you do not understand like I did.

Hope this helps anyone.